# How to allow the execution of an application requiring administrator rights to a specific user?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I'am on Windows 10 pro version and I want to allow a user to run an application with administrator rights.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the application and select Run as Administrator. If the user is an Administrator, an UAC prompt will ask a yes/no question in order to be sure this is what you want.

If the user is not an Administrator, this prompt will ask for credentials of a user with Administrator permissions.

In order to make sure the user is an Administrator, ensure that this user is a member of the local group: Administrators. A reboot is required if you change this, before it will be effective.

If you do not want to grand Administrator rights to the user, nor give them the password for an administrator account, you can't run that specific program as Administrator.

That said, most reasons why a program wants administrative rights is because it wants to write to a location the user has no access to. If you know where this program writes, you can set rights to include write rights. Right click that folder, select properties, and head for the security tab. Either add the user and give write permissions, or set write permissions to one of the existing groups that the user is a member of. This will also allow other users to get the same access in the future.

A program may also want to write to the registry. The same can be done in the registry, but it is often hard to determine where in the registry a program wants to write to.

Finally, it is also possible that the program has a service it controls. If this is the case, then you really do need administrative access to use this program. In 99% of the cases, there is no service involved though.